# Return list of values from SQL Subquery inside a View

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

What I have here are four tables (Study, Publication, Location, Drugs) and a join table caused by the Many to Many relation between Drugs and Study.

I have created a view with the following script:

```
SELECT 
        `l`.`country` AS `country`,
        `l`.`latitude` AS `latitude`,
        `l`.`longitude` AS `longitude`,
        `l`.`region` AS `region`,
        `s`.`enrolment` AS `enrolment`,
        `s`.`diagnosis` AS `diagnosis`,
        `s`.`registry_ID` AS `registry_ID`,
        `s`.`status` AS `status`,
        `s`.`site_name` AS `site_name`,
        `s`.`study_no` AS `study_no`,
        `p`.`pub_year` AS `pub_year`,
        `p`.`URL` AS `url`,
        `p`.`authors` AS `authors`,
        `p`.`pubMedId` AS `pubMedId`,
        `p`.`pub_title` AS `pub_title`,
        `d`.`name` AS `name`
    FROM
        (((`VL`.`Location` `l`
        join `VL`.`Study` `s`)
        join `VL`.`Publication` `p`)
        join `VL`.`Drugs` `d`)
    WHERE
        ((`l`.`id` = `s`.`location_id`)
            and (`p`.`study_id` = `s`.`id`)
            and `d`.`id` in ((SELECT 
                `VL`.`Study_Drugs`.`drugses_id`
            FROM
                `VL`.`Study_Drugs`
            WHERE
                (`VL`.`Study_Drugs`.`studiesList_id` = `s`.`id`))))
```

Now, what I need is for the subquery to give me the complete list of drugs that can be found in each Study, which is what happens when I do this query alone:

```
SELECT d.name
FROM VL.Drugs d
WHERE d.id IN(SELECT drugses_id
            FROM Study_Drugs
            WHERE studiesList_id = 'whatever id')
```

So, the question is Why does it return me the full list on the query alone, but not in the same query being used as part of the View's script?

`EDIT` to include sample data and wished results:

Study:

```
'2', 'Spleen', '70', NULL, 'KALA-AZAR MEDICAL RESEARCH CENTER, RAMBAG ROAD , MUZAFFARPUR,  BIHAR -842001, INDIA ', 'Published', '75', NULL, '68'
```

Publication:

```
'12', 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10897369', 'Sundar S, Gupta LB, Rastogi V, Agrawal G, Murray HW.', '10897369', 'Short-course, cost-effective drugs with amphotericin B-fat emulsion cures visceral leishmaniasis.', '2000', '2'
```

Location:

```
'68', 'India', '26.118589', '85.400719', 'India Subcontinent'
```

Drugs (when doing the subquery alone):

```
'Pentavalent Antimonial'
'Miltefosine'
```

So, what I want from my View would be all this information, except a few unnecesary fields from Study and Publication.  With the final value (Drugs) being formed of all those drugs related to the Study's id, what I get now per row is as follows:

```
'India', '26.118589', '85.400719', 'India Subcontinent', '70', 'Spleen', NULL, 'Published', 'KALA-AZAR MEDICAL RESEARCH CENTER, RAMBAG ROAD , MUZAFFARPUR,  BIHAR -842001, INDIA ', '75', '2000', 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10897369', 'Sundar S, Gupta LB, Rastogi V, Agrawal G, Murray HW.', '10897369', 'Short-course, cost-effective drugs with amphotericin B-fat emulsion cures visceral leishmaniasis.', 'Pentavalent Antimonial'
```

As you see, the last value is formed by only the first drug of the list

Comment: Hmmm, you have a lot of joins and conditions in the `where` clause.  Those would tend to filter out rows.

Comment: The join conditions are to avoid duplicates of rows, as I have references of Location in Study and references of Study in Publication.  It shouldn't affect the list of drugs. (I think :0)

Comment: Provide sample data and sample of the expected results please.

Comment: Just edited original question with sample data, wished results and actual results

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your view to look like this

```
create view your_view
as
select s.*, d.* --explicit name that stuff
from        Location l
inner join  Study s on l.id = s.location_id
inner join  Study_Drugs sd on s.id = sd.study_id
inner join  Drugs d on d.id = sd.drugs_id
inner join  Publications p on s.id = p.study_id;


select * from your_view where study_id = 1; -- whatever id
```

I am not sure what you want the publications for.
Please use the "new" notation with "inner joins" instead of the "where"-clause which you used.

Comment: LOL new? since 1992? I agree the original syntax was horrible. But people need to understand this is NOT a new syntax, it is older than many of the people who are doing the programming.

Comment: That's why I used the quotation-marks around "new".

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, just tried with your version, I get exactly the same ResultSet as with my own.

  I need all the data from Publications and Studies as the ResultSet from the View is going to a csv file, which will then be parsed to JSON so the data can be displayed on a web application.

Comment: I think I don't understand your exact question then.

Comment: For every Study there can be a series of Drugs that have been used, and every Drug could have been used for several Studies, so we have a Many to Many there, which is handled by a Join Table.  What I need is to represent that list of Drugs in the rows of the ResultSet from my view
  I managed to do it from the short query, but not from the view, so the question is, Why won't it work for me from the View?

Comment: I guess you are not having publications or something like that in all of your tables. Change my considered query from "inner joins" to "left joins" and check if some values are empty.